# Datatables date range filter for universal time

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am trying to add a filter to my datatable that allows me to search for entries with certain date from a range (for example, 2020-10-5 to 2020-10-10). However my date column must have dates formatted such as this: "Wed Nov 25 2020 15:43:58 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)".

[date range filter][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0os8K.png

[date column][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNdQe.png

The code below is what I tried in order to parse from format yyyy-mm-dd to something similair to the universal time however I am having trouble figuring out how I can compare as it involves a string. Wondering if anyone has any suggestions?

#min and #max are my min and max date filters

```
        $('#min').keyup(function() {
            table.fnDraw();
        });

        $('#max').keyup(function() {
            table.fnDraw();
        });

 <script th:inline="javascript">
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
            var iMin = $('#min').val().split("-");
            iMin[1] = monthDict[iMin[1]];
            var ret = [iMin[1], iMin[2], iMin[0]];
            var ret = ret.join(" ");
            $('#min').val() = ret

            var iMax = $('#min').val().split("-");
            iMax[1] = monthDict[iMax[1]];
            var ret2 = [iMax[1], iMax[2], iMax[0]];
            var ret2 = ret2.join(" ");
            $('#min').val() = ret2

            if (ret == "" && ret2 == "") {
                return true;
            } else if (ret == "" && iVersion <= ret2) {
                return true;
            } else if (ret <= iVersion && "" == ret2) {
                return true;
            } else if (ret <= iVersion && iVersion <= ret2) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );
```

Comment: Do you receive the data already in this format? Or do you parse it into this format yourself, before it is displayed? It sounds like you are parsing it for yourself...

Comment: ...if you are parsing it yourself, take a look at [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data). Each value in a DataTables cell can have 3 different versions: (1) the display value - what you see in the web page; (2) the sort value - used when data is sorted; (3) the filter value - used by filter logic. By default, all these values are the same. You can control the different values by using a `column.render()` function - an example is shown in the link. This allows you to use a much more filter-friendly value, in contrast to the more user-friendly display value.

Comment: @andrewjames I receive the data into my datatable as the universal format and I am trying to filter in that column from a specific date to another

Comment: @andrewjames if I understand correctly, I can make it so that if I click filter it takes my 2020-10-2 and converts it into something such as Dec 02 2020 and looks for that instead of 2020-10-2.

Comment: You still need to do the conversion between formats yourself - so this approach may not really help you.

Comment: Looks as though you can use a simple [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) on that, though you might be better with a library such as momentjs (though it's been replaced with others now). Then it's simple as anything to comparse between. One thing to be careful is the input you recieve might need to have a day added to either end. If you work up a JSFiddle then we can take a look with you.